# Content Porter Installation - hash error

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

We are getting below error while installing content porter from CME- using IE

- application validation did not succeed. unable to continue
- File, Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.CommonFacade.dll, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.

This happened after we tried installing a patch for CP(hotfix 3.1.0.79095).

Can some one suggest a solution.

--- We are in the process of Upgrading to Sp2 Content Porter and the issue is resolved.

Comment: Could you please let us know, what was actual issue & how did you resolve it?

Comment: We have opted to upgrade CP to SP2 to avoid further issues with patching.

Answer (score 5):

It seems conflict issue of older and new dlls. Restart your Tridion services and reset the IIS pool of SDL Tridion website.

Please also refer below links

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228998.aspx)

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437446/clickonce-error-different-computed-hash-than-specified-in-manifest-when-transf)

Comment: We have tried restarting the COM+,Tridion Services and IIS still the issue persists.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check if it helps also Google about "ClickOnce Deployment Issue" if above links do not help

Comment: We first checked on One Click Deployment. As part of applying patches(ID mentioned in question) we have replaced few dll files later we reverted with backup dll files. Upon restarting COM+ we faced this issue.

Comment: MSDN link above talks about different set of problems and their solutions related to click once deployment, i think you should give it a try(if not already tried) after patching Content porter again..

Answer (score 1):

We are in the process of upgrading the CP to 2009 SP2 to avoid these issues with Patches/reverting as final solution.

Answer (score 0):

For SDL Tridion SP1 HR1 try to install Content Porter 2009 SP1 just with Hotfix 75326. 
It has been working on my previous installations without any related issues.